# Tableau: Different Fields, Same Filter

Tags: filter, tableau-api, dashboard

Let's say I had a list of transactions with the buyer and the seller. People are often in both columns. I want to have one worksheet with information about the sales, and one about the purchases. However, I want to be able to pick a single name in the filter on the dashboard and have it bring up their sales in the one worksheet and purchases in the other. Is there a way to do this since they are different fields? (Just using the same values in a lot of cases)

Comment: This may be best solved by structuring your data carefully. If, for example, you stored the data using two columns for each customer, one recording their name , the other recording whether they were a buyer or seller, then a filter based on the name will recover *all* their transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just created a sample data to see whether I can replicate your question.

I'm sending you a link with my example
https://public.tableau.com/views/Question/Dashboard?:embed=y&:display_count=yes

Sample data used:

```
+--------------+--------+--------+--------+
| Transactions | Buyer  | Seller | Amount |
+--------------+--------+--------+--------+
|          123 | Matt   | Jackie |   1000 |
|          456 | Jackie | Matt   |   1500 |
|          587 | Phill  | Jackie |   2000 |
|          874 | Matt   | Phill  |   1345 |
|          547 | Jackie | John   |   1000 |
|          514 | John   | Jackie |   1500 |
|          549 | Phill  | Matt   |   2000 |
|          451 | Jackie | John   |   1345 |
|          159 | Matt   | Joseph |   1000 |
|          457 | Jackie | Matt   |   1500 |
|          114 | Joseph | Matt   |   2000 |
+--------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Steps:

1. Create one parameter with the list of all buyers and seller.

`I have called it "Parameter"`

2- On "Buyer -  Sample sheet" - Create a filter on the dimension Buyer.

`Add dimension as filter --> Edit filter --> Condition ([Buyer] = [Parameter])`

3-  On "Seller - Sample sheet" - Create a filter on  the dimension Seller.

`Add dimention as filter --> Edit filter --> Condition ([Seller] = [Parameter])`

4- On your dashboard

You will have Your seller sheet,  the two sheets and  the parameter. Every time You use the parameter, both sheets will change.

Hope you find it useful and it answers your question.

Comment: Wow. This is exactly what I was looking for. This is fantastic. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that. You're very welcome. Please feel free to reach out if any question.